# How to exclude some query from inline Django admin model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django `2.0.3`, Python `3.6.1`.

I try to filter QuerySet of ForeignKey field on inline admin model (Django Admin).

```
# ./app/models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


# ./app/admin.py

class PriceInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id',)
    inlines = [
        PriceInlineAdmin
    ]
```

How to exclude from `PriceInlineAdmin` QuerySet colours with name `blue`?

Comment: Have you looked at ``ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey``? You could override the queryset there. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: This is not working in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to do it this way

```
class PriceInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "name":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Price.objects.exclude(color__name="blue")
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```